# Unable to send push notification to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, javaapns

I am sending push-notification to i-phone using Java APNs. Am able to send notification to one app but am not able to send notification to other apps. 
For first app (Successful sending push notification) am using

```
String json1= "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Testing.. (3)\",\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
PushNotificationPayload payLoad = null;
        try {
            payLoad = PushNotificationPayload.fromJSON(json1);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Push.payload(payLoad , "/home/owner/Downloads/v.p12", null, false, "97884fe9ffeb6f5....");
```

and for other app (unsuccessful) am using the same

```
 String json1= "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Testing.. (3)\",\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
    PushNotificationPayload payLoad = null;
            try {
                payLoad = PushNotificationPayload.fromJSON(json1);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Push.payload(payLoad , "/home/owner/Downloads/app.p12", null, false, "191cdc5a8c8c1cb19597a4fd....");
```

any help ??

Comment: first check your .pem file.

Comment: am not using .pem am using .p12. because javaapns doesn’t allow .pem.

Comment: Device setting for receiving notification enabled? I think if you can send to one phone but can't send  another phone, It should be a client side problem.

Comment: On the same phone I have 2 apps . device setting for receiving notification is enabled. Am able to send notification on 1st app but not on the 2nd app.

Comment: I thought you failed to send to other phones.There is a configuration for each app.Even if they are on the same phone.Did you check it?

Comment: yes i have checked it

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution to my problem. am not sure if it is the correct way or not.

1. Create .p12 or .pem using your .cert file from the keychain for app1.
2. clean the keychain store(where all your .cert file exist).
3. download the .cert for app2.
4. generate the .p12 or .pem for app2.

now I can successfully send notification on both the apps on same device.